# Error when trying to use push into a 2d array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to push a value into a 2d array but I'm getting the error:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Here's a MWE of my code:

```
var saida = new Array()
for (i in dbInfo){
  saida[i].push(i)
}
```

Where `dbInfo` is a range in my sheet, but can be replaced by any other range for this example. I need the output to be a 2d array so I can work out the values into the sheet.

Comment: [don't use `for...in` on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in)

Comment: Setting `saida` to a new array is not defining `saida[i]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just created the array the array is empty. So saida[n] will be undefined no matter what value n has.

You need to first create it. Then you can push into it.

Maybe something like this? Not sure what you need.

```
var saida = new Array()
for (i in dbInfo){
  saida[i]=[]
  saida[i].push(i)
}
```

Comment: In this case it would be better to do directly `saida[i] = [i];`

Comment: yeah correct I was just explaining why he can't push stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If `dbInfo` is an object of type `Range` from the Sheet, then the returned array after using `getValues` is already a 2D array so a simple assignment will suffice:

```
function addData() {
  // your other code
  let dbInfoVals = dbInfo.getValues();
  let saida = dbInfoVals;
  console.log(saida)
}
```

However, if `dbInfo` is a 1D array, transforming into a 2D one can be done by using the `splice` method in JavaScript:

```
function addData() {
  // your other code
  let saida = [];
  while (dbInfo.length){ 
    saida.push(dbInfo.splice(0, 2));
  }
  console.log(saida);
}
```

The second parameter of `splice` will give you the number of columns, so you might need to adjust this to match your range accordingly.

#### Reference

- [Range Class - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
- [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define your array to 2d
Eg: `int[,] arr= new string[3, 2];`

You will need to iterate twice.

```
for(int col1 = 0; col1 < arr.GetLength(0); col1++){
   for(int row1 = 0; row1 < arr.GetLength(1); row1++)
   { 
     arr[col1,row1] =  2; 
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is JavaScript (see tags); there is no `int[,]` type in JavaScript.